# Connecting Google's Tensorboard to Vertex AI AutoML

Tags: tensorboard, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there a way to connect Google's Vertex AI **Tensorboard** to **AutoML**? - I remember a brief mention in a coursera specialization but don't know where it was.

Answer (score 2):

Vertex AI Tensorboard is only [used for custom models](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/experiments/tensorboard-training) that are trained using Tensorflow since it can produce Tensorboard logs. These logs will be used by Tensorboard to create visualizations.

Unfortunately AutoML does not produce Tensorboard logs since AutoML is a tool that trains based on the given labeled dataset and does not have control to tweak other training parameters. But if you are using AutoML and wants to see model details like precision, confidence threshold, etc. the model will return a [evaluation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/evaluating-automl-models#evaluation_metrics_returned_by).

> Vertex AI returns several different evaluation metrics such as
> precision, recall, and confidence thresholds. The metrics that Vertex
> AI returns depend on your model's objective. For example, Vertex AI
> provides different evaluation metrics for an image classification
> model compared to an image object detection model.

Example of the model evaluation:

[image]